# IEEEtran, standalone, and XeLaTex: do not crop

Tags: xetex, ieeetran, standalone, crop

I am using the following MWE.

```
\documentclass[tikz,class=IEEEtran]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node[draw, line width=5pt,blue, fill=green](boxofgreen) {This box is green};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

When I compile with XeLatex the output PDF is not cropped.

However, when I compile with pdftex or lualatex the output PDF is cropped.

My file do not have blank lines at the end or before \end{document}

Is there any way to make it crop for XeLaTex?

Answer (score 6):

The class tests for \pdfoutput. So you could fool it by defining it (and setting it to 1). But be aware that this could confuse other packages which test for pdfoutput too. Also IEEEtran is not meant for xelatex, so other things can be wrong too (e.g. fonts). I would advise not to use it together with xelatex.

```
\newcommand\pdfoutput{1} %bad hack for xelatex
\documentclass[tikz,class=IEEEtran]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node[draw, line width=5pt,blue, fill=green](boxofgreen) {This box is green};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```